# SKShapeNode: How to set String to name of SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a wheel in my app. I need to retrieve the value of the slice/wedge where it stops.

This code:

```
print(wheelScene.atPoint(CGPoint(x: wheelScene.frame.midX,     y:wheelScene.frame.maxY)))
```

Returns this:

```
<SKShapeNode> name:'9' accumulatedFrame:{{-257.28399658203125,     -187.08700561523438}, {1126.8409423828125, 1216.89501953125}}
```

From the Apple Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483136-name

The declaration is

```
var name: String? { get set }
```

Not quite sure how to use the `{ get set }`

So my question is how do I retrieve the name of the SKShapeNode for use in a String?

Edit:

Got it:

```
    var node = wheelScene.atPoint(CGPoint(x: wheelScene.frame.midX, y:wheelScene.frame.maxY))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this as an attribute of any `SKNode`and therefore any `SKShapeNode`.

You can use `<#SKNode#>.name = "Any name"` to set it.

or

You can use `<#SKNode#>`.name to get it.

**Example:**

```
var node = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
node.name = "Bob"

print(node.name)
```

Comment: I guess I didn't ask the question right. I don't know which node the wheel will land at. I need the name of a node at a point. See edit